# Бесплатный хостинг

Tags: хостинг

Как можно прикрутить купленный домен к бесплатному хостингу, возможно ли это?

Comment: используй github pages как бесплатный хостинг. и прикрути к нему свое имя: http://isizov.ru/kak-dobavit-domen-k-github-pages/

Comment: Возможно. Для ответа на вопрос "как" следует обратиться в техподдержку хостинга.

Comment: бесплатные хостинги обычно предоставляют домен третьего (или четвертого) уровня. У регистратора (который пропишет Ваш dns для домена) нужно прописать CNAME запись с указанием на домен бесплатного хостинга. В результате к Вашему сайту можно будет достучаться по двум именам одновременно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В панели управления доменом следует прописать DNS
При покупке\заказе хостинга хостер обычно высылает адреса NS-серверов вместе с вашими данными для хостинга.

Обычно выглядят они так (либо как IP-адреса):

```
ns1.hostersite.com
ns2.hostersite.com
```

Эти адреса следует прописать в настройках DNS у домена в панели управления доменом (там где домен регистрировался)

После сохранения настроек DNS должно пройти до 48 часов, пока DNS обновятся глобально, после этого ваш сайт станет доступен (домен прикрепится к хостингу)

Соответственно на хостинге у вас должен быть создан сайт с именем вашего домена